# error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

I'm trying to use npm scripts (onchange, parallelshell) but when running npm start, it returns the following error: I tried cleaning the npm cache and re-installing npm modules but it didn't work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3f6TI.png)

here is the log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v14.2.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle confusion@1.0.0~prestart: confusion@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle confusion@1.0.0~start: confusion@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle confusion@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle confusion@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\coursera\Bootstrap4\conFusion\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\SASM\NASM;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\;C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle confusion@1.0.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\coursera\Bootstrap4\conFusion
10 silly lifecycle confusion@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm run watch:all' ]
11 silly lifecycle confusion@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle confusion@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: confusion@1.0.0 start: `npm run watch:all`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1051:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
14 verbose pkgid confusion@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\coursera\Bootstrap4\conFusion
16 verbose Windows_NT 6.3.9600
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v14.2.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error confusion@1.0.0 start: `npm run watch:all`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the confusion@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

and here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "confusion",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is a website for Ristorante Con Fusion",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run watch:all",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "scss": "node-sass -o css/ css/",
    "watch:scss": "onchange \"css/*.scss\" -- npm run scss",
    "watch:all": "parallelshell \"npm run watch:scss\" \"npm run lite\" "
  },
  "author": "Wafaa",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^2.3.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "onchange": "^7.0.2",
    "parallelshell": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "bootstrap-social": "^5.1.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1"
  }
}
```